# Automate Generate scripts for database objects

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

How to automate Generate scripts for database objects using stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

If you want to migrate objects definitions and data to another database you can use a [SQL Server Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/types-of-replication?view=sql-server-ver15) - for example read about `Transactional replication`. It will constantly sync the definitions and the data of the specified objects.

If you want to generate scripts for once, you can use the SQL Server Management Studio Generate Scripts options (right click on a database -> Tasks -> Generate Scripts:

[image]

There are plenty of options. For example to get not only the tables definitions, but the data, too:

[image]

Anyway, for larger tables the generated file might be to big to be open by the SSMS again, so the data can be transferred with [bcp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15).

If you want to create own procedure for scripting the definitions of particular objects you will query the DMV:

```
sys.objects
sys.tables
sys.columns
sys.indexes
etc
```

There you will find the details for each objects (columns, types, index keys). For the routines, you can use:

```
SELECT [ROUTINE_NAME]
      ,[ROUTINE_DEFINITION]
FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[ROUTINES]

SELECT OBJECT_NAME([id]) 
      ,[text]
FROM [SYSCOMMENTS]

SELECT OBJECT_NAME([object_id])
      ,[definition]
FROM [sys].[sql_modules]
```

Comment: Thank you. but I want to create SP to generate scripts for once

Comment: @Shimma scripts for what ? and if it for once, use the SSMS studio.